# Good text on nonlinear regression (M.S. graduate-level)?

Tags: references, nonlinear-regression

I've covered a linear models sequence where the classes discussed linear models using matrices, covering various experimental designs (split-plot, for example), ANOVA using matrices, and ending with generalized linear mixed-effects models. I can't see myself learning more about regression without using matrix algebra.

I would like to learn about nonlinear regression. I believe this will be covered in a future course, but alas, no textbook list is provided.

Are there any good texts that cover what I'm looking for?

Comment: It depends on your background - if you are familiar with Econometric terminology (often differs slightly from traditional statistical terminology), then Greene's *Econometric Analysis* pdf has one chapter on nonlinear regression techniques that I found very helpful as an introduction. Generally, it also depends what kind of nonlinear regressions you want to run (logistic regressions, poisson regressions, ... ). On a sidenote, nonlinear regressions are also commonly put under the header 'Generalized Linear Models (GLM)', so maybe that helps you, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two pretty standard references would be

Bates, D.M. & Watts, D.G. (1988),
Nonlinear Regression Analysis and Its Applications,
Wiley, New York.

Seber, G.A.F. &  Wild, C.J. (1989),
Nonlinear Regression,
Wiley, New York.